# JS moment check if now is after one minute does not work

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I need to check if the current time based on the previous time.

```
const created = moment(new Date());
const oneMinuteLater = created.add(1, 'minutes');

setTimeout(() => {
  const now = moment();
  // Returns false
  console.log('oneMinutePass', now.isAfter(oneMinuteLater, 'minute'));
}, 60000);
```

Why it returns false if one minute is passed?

Comment: Are you able to print out the timestamp for `now` and `oneMinuteLater` ?

Comment: 2018-01-15T11:54:35+02:00
2018-01-15T11:54:36+02:00

Comment: I'm not sure why I'm getting this output.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do. You have set the timeout to 60 seconds, and there you test if it is 60 seconds after you set the time... If you wan't it to be 60 seconds later, it is enough to have set the timeout to 60 seconds as you have. You don't need to check with moment if it has been 60 seconds.

Comment: After one minute, now will be equal to oneMinuteLater. You should use `isSameOrAfter()`

Comment: @Weedoze Thanks! It's working.

Comment: @undefined I'll post it as an answer. Mark it as the answer so this post is solved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After one minute, `now` will be *equal* to `oneMinuteLater` and not *after*.

Start

```
now = 15/01/2018 11:08:00
oneMinuteLater = 15/01/2018 11:08:01
```

One minute later

```
now = 15/01/2018 11:08:01
oneMinuteLater = 15/01/2018 11:08:01
//now === oneMinuteLater
```

The solution is to use `isSameOrAfter()`